# Походження фразеологізму "бувати в бувальцях"

Tags: синоніми, фразеологізми

[Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D1%8F%D1%85)

> Бувати в бувальцях - багато в житті ба­чити, зазнавати.

[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53393/356174.html)

> **бува́ти / побува́ти у бува́льцях**. 1. Багато бачити, зазнавати в житті. Левонтій Петрович тягався по світах, бував у бувальцях, служив
> в москалях, був військовим писарем (І. Нечуй-Левицький);
> **Побував-таки** (старий мандрівник) **в бувальцях**, бачив білий світ. Атож! Довелось ковтнути і солоного, і гіркого (С. Журахович); //
> яких. Опинятися у складних, перев. небезпечних ситуаціях. Кумові
> доводилося бувати у всіляких бувальцях (С. Чорнобривець). 2. Мати
> непривабливий вигляд, довго чи часто використовуватися; бути не новим.
> Вигляд у мене був непривабливий. Сірий простенький костюм, що вже й до
> цього бував у бувальцях, зовсім зім’явся (Ю. Збанацький).

Цікавить походження даного фразеологізму. Чи має він синоніми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фразеологізм "бувати в бувальцях" утворений із двох українських слів: дієслова "бути" та іменника "[бувалець](http://sum.in.ua/s/buvalecj)" (Людина з великим життєвим досвідом, яка багато бачила, зазнала у своєму житті).

Синоніми: бувати в пригоді, тягатися по світах (джерела [1](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D1%8F%D1%85), [2](https://dovidka.biz.ua/buvati-v-buvaltsyah-frazeologizm/))